# std method for packing data

Tags: c++, templates, std

Suppose I have a struct that I want packed (because I am communicating with another program, and it is simpler to just pack all of the data so that you can guarantee it meshes).

In `gcc` to pack a struct you do this:

```
struct __attribute((packed)) Mine { /* Members here */ };
```

Is there a template defined in the `std` library to do this?

The reason I ask is because there is `std::aligned_storage`, which is extremely helpful on the alignment end of things, and it seems logical to have a similar thing for packing data.

So does this exist?

Comment: I don't know of a standard, but the `pack` pragma seems to be supported on both [`GCC`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Layout-Pragmas.html#Structure-Layout-Pragmas) and [`MSVC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx). `clang` seems to follow `MSVC`'s version of `pack`, though simple usage for `GCC` and `MSVC` is compatible with both.

Comment: I'd recommend using a real serialization format instead.  [msgpack](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c) and [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial) are both very fast and incredibly easy to use from C++.   I've never used Boost serialization, but a lot of people like that too.  Even if you know the packing, there are tons of reasons to not shoot a raw struct over the wire.

Comment: @Taywee For the record I need precise control over what I am doing, because I am communicating directly with the FAT file system, which requires weird stuff like 12 bits assigned for this and 6 bits assigned for that......I am not sure if those suggestions would do the job.....that said I haven't looked into them

Comment: Can't upvote @Taywee 's comment enough. If you have to manually serialize, do. Counting on all implementations to pack exactly the same way will lead to a hellish nightmare.

Comment: @DarthRubik If you need to do that kind of packing, you need to manually fill a memory buffer, and be sure your endianness is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't exist. Standard explicitly says that packing fields in struct is implementation defined.

It also mentions that for bit fields the way bits flow from one bit field to next is also implementation defined (I get that you are using bitfields too). Sorry, but you'd have to code explicitly for your compiler(s).

Answer (score 0):

While it's hard to prove a negative, I'm sure the answer is no.

Fundamentally, `std` is almost entirely implementable in fairly well-defined C++, with only the occasional need for limited compiler coordination (e.g. `std::size_t` is the type of `sizeof` expressions). The feature you describe would be fully at odds with this notion.

Comment: Then why is there `alignof` and `alignas`?

Comment: Note that `alignas` does not guarantee that you get the alignment you ask for - just that you get *at least* that - it may be bigger..

Comment: @JesperJuhl I realize that, but it guarantees that I can store the data that I need to store....